# Como crear un archivo con una ruta relativa

Tags: java, archivo, txt

les tengo una duda. Tengo que realizar un trabajo el cual consta de generar un archivo txt, este archivo tiene que llevar una lista (la cual ya tengo) pero tengo problemas para generar el archivo, se tiene que abrir en otra computadora diferente a la mia por lo que tengo entendido que se debe usar una ruta relativa, pero no estoy seguro de como hacerlo, aqui esta mi codigo:

```
            System.out.println("\n\nDesea crear un archivo de texto que pueda guardar la informacion?\nPara confirmar presione 1, para declinar presione 0");
        int persistir_datos = scanner.nextInt();
        if(persistir_datos == 1)
        {
            //se instancia un objeto de tipo File
            File informacionZ1;
            try
            {
                informacionZ1 = new File("C:/Arreglos dinámicos java/Informacion estacionamiento Zona 1.txt");
                if(informacionZ1.createNewFile())
                {
                    System.out.println("Se ha creado el archivo exitosamente");
                }
                
            }
            catch(Throwable e)
            {
                System.out.println("No se ha logrado crear el archivo, vuelva a intentar");
            }
        }
```

Lo que quiero hacer es que este se cree ya sea en la carpeta donde se encuentra el proyecto o bien, en el escritorio de la computadora donde se abra, como puedo hacer eso? hasta ahora solo me tira el error, no logra crear el archivo. Me podrian ayudar?

Answer (score 0):

Para crear un fichero en una ruta relativa, por ejemplo el directorio de tu aplicación, basta con no indicar ningún directorio en el constructor de la clase File:

```
new File("fichero.txt");
```

Así, el fichero que has indicado (fichero.txt) se creará en el directorio de tu aplicación.

No es buena idea utilizar rutas absolutas si quieres que tu código sea portable. Salvo contadas excepciones, usa rutas relativas. El escritorio no es un buen destino, sólo te serviría para SO Windows.

Saludos

Answer (score 0):

puede hacer directamente tanto para la creacion como para la lectura desde la ubicación del ejecutable:

```java
new File("./archivo.txt");
```